# Инициализация динамического двумерного массива строк

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Сабж. Ругается на `')' expected but ',' found` в строке

```
ArrayBox : array of array of string =
(
   ( 'бла', /*тут курсор при компиляции*/ 'бла1' ), // 10 элементов
   ( /*почти те же самые строки*/ ), // 6 элементов
   ( /**/ ) // 8 элементов
);
```

Comment: Вся проблема в том что вы хотите при инициализации добавить разное количество элементов к тому же в динамический массив.

Answer (score 1):

Динамические массивы так инициализировать нельзя. Нужно сначала задать размер массива (`SetLength`). Потом можно заполнять значения. Сделать это можно, например, в секции `initialization`.

Comment: >Сделать это можно в секции Initialization. А зачем там? Я бы рекомендовал инициализировать массив в нужном месте, в вызове метода или где то локально.

Comment: **Иногда** это удобно для библиотечной функции. Что бы не проверять постоянно заполненность массива мы в самом начале работы программы заполняем инициализирующими значениями, а программист потом может дополнить/изменить массив.

Comment: да, в таком случае удобно.